# Login screen intermediate on exposed server port

Tags: web-apps, web-server, authentication, login

I need to expose a web interface of a project at work. It rests on our servers and needs to be exposed to the whole internet.
However, there's no security at all to access the web interface of the project, but this is a must!

Do you know any intermediate web interface ("batteries included") we could use in front of our project's exposed port?

Like some kind of router with embedded authentication system, like Konga, but with a login screen.

Comment: Maybe you can use a web proxy server that requires authentication